# Diagonal concatenate of two dataframes not working in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, python-polars

I'm trying to concatenate two dataframes with Polars in Python, and it keeps throwing an error despite my syntax appearing to be correct based on the docs.

Specifically, I've got `ldf_a` with `shape: (4, 33)` and `ldf_b` with `shape: (4, 33)`.

When I say

`ldf_c = pl.concat([ldf_a,ldf_b,],rechunk=True,how="vertical")`

or

`ldf_c = pl.concat([ldf_a,ldf_b,],rechunk=True,how="diagonal")`

it throws an error saying

> cannot vstack: because column names in the two DataFrames do not match for left.name='type_of_lapse' != right.name='type_of_record'

Now, I don't believe that for a second, because when I say `ldf_a.columns` and `ldf_b.columns` I can very clearly see that the column names *are* the same. And even if they weren't, isn't that what the `diagonal` method is supposed to solve? Thoughts? Also, let me know if you need further clarification!

Edit:
Here's an example of ldf_a

| policy_key | type_of_record | type_of_lapse | coverage_substatus | actual_mortality_count | actual_persistency_count | last_effective_date_in_exp | max_issue_age | max_issue_date | max_paid_to_date | max_plan_gender_code | max_risk_code | max_par_code | max_distribution | max_substandard_multiplier | max_current_volume | max_segment_indicator | has_lapse | has_death | max_effective_date | max_transaction_date | min_coverage_status | min_coverage_substatus | max_coverage_status | max_date_of_death | max_cause_of_death | max_agnis_plan_code | max_roe_line_of_business | max_coverage_years | source | 16 | 35 | unpaid_matured_endowment_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | V |  | 16 | 0 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 1962-10-01 | 1994-09-01 | U | XX | P | Mass | 1 | 500 | K | N | N | 2019-10-01 | 00 | 05 | 10 | 15 |  |  | 12345 | 07 | 99 | EXP | 2005-12-31 | 2007-12-31 |  |

And here's an example of ldf_b

| policy_key | type_of_record | type_of_lapse | coverage_substatus | actual_mortality_count | actual_persistency_count | last_effective_date_in_exp | max_issue_age | max_issue_date | max_paid_to_date | max_plan_gender_code | max_risk_code | max_par_code | max_distribution | max_substandard_multiplier | max_current_volume | max_segment_indicator | has_lapse | has_death | max_effective_date | max_transaction_date | min_coverage_status | min_coverage_substatus | max_coverage_status | max_date_of_death | max_cause_of_death | max_agnis_plan_code | max_roe_line_of_business | max_coverage_years | source | 16 | 35 | unpaid_matured_endowment_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | V |  | 16 | 0 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 1962-10-01 | 1994-09-01 | U | XX | P | Mass | 1 | 500 | K | N | N | 2019-10-01 | 00 | 05 | 10 | 15 |  |  | 12345 | 07 | 99 | EXP | 2005-12-31 | 2007-12-31 |  |

Comment: Can you provide example dataframes? that would be very helpful

Comment: What happens when you have just the first three columns (so including `type_of_lapse`, which is what the error is about)? And could you provide your example dataframes defined as code, so people can run the example for themselves? Final remark, given you name your dataframes `ldf_x`, I am assuming that they are lazy. Note that concatting lazy dataframes using diagonal is not supported: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5082